# fluent nhibernate - storing and retrieving three classes in/from one table

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Noob question.

I have this situation where I have these objects:

```
class Address
{      
   string Street;
   string City;
   ...
}

class User
{
   string UserID;
   Address BillingAddress;
   Address MailingAddress;
   ...
}
```

What is the proper way of storing this data using (fluent) nHibernate? I could use a separate Address table and create a reference, but they are 1:1 relationships so I don't really want to incur the overhead of a join. Ideally I would store this as a single flat record.

So, my question is, what is the proper way of storing an instance of class 'User' in such a way that it stores its contents and also the two addresses as a single record? My knowledge is failing me on how I can store this information in such a way that the two Address records get different column names (e.g. BillingAddress_Street and MailingAddress_Street, for example), and also how to read a record back into a User instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These kinds of structures are referred to as a `component`. They're a normalized structure, and perfectly acceptable mechanism for representing data.

In Fluent NHibernate there are a couple of ways to map components. Firstly there's inline mappings, and then the external [ComponentMap](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#ComponentMap.3CT.3E). I would recommend the latter in your situation, and in any scenario where you have a component that appears multiple times (either in the same entity, or across your domain).

---

### Inline Components

To map a component, the simplest way is to use the `Component` method and specify how the component is composed using the body lambda.

```
  Component(x => x.BillingAddress, addr =>
  {
    addr.Map(x => x.Street);
    addr.Map(x => x.City);
  });
```

That's your address mapped. You'll need to repeat this for both addresses.

---

### ComponentMap

The inline definition works fine for one-off components, but it can quickly become tiresome when you have multiple instances of the same component. `ComponentMap` solves this by extracting your component out into a self-contained, reusable, definition. You just use it exactly the same way as you do `ClassMap`.

```
public class AddressMap : ComponentMap<Address>
{
  public AddressMap()
  {
    Map(x => x.Street);
    Map(x => x.City);
  }
}
```

Then in your `ClassMap`, you just need to use the bodyless `Component` method; this instructs Fluent NHibernate to search for a `ComponentMap` matching the type of the property (if one isn't found, you'll know about it).

```
Component(x => x.BillingAddress);
Component(x => x.MailingAddress);
```

With the `ComponentMap`, column prefixes are automatically created as necessary based on the property that contains the component. If you need to customise this there's the `ColumnPrefix` method that's chained off the bodyless `Component` call.

```
Component(x => x.BillingAddress)
  .ColumnPrefix("Billing_");
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a great explanation! took me a while to figure out that the ComponentMap was not available in 1.0 RTM. But I did get it to work with a post RTM build. (Wasn't sure what you meant by 'external' in your post, you mean there is a way to add ComponentMap to the 1.0 RTM?

Comment: One other minor question -- not sure how NH decides to build the table, but it's creating: <billing columns><mailing columns><rest of user table> any way I can control it to create: <rest of user table><billing column><mailing column> ? At the very least I want my primary key from the User class to be the first column in the table (I'm anal that way! :)